# How to set light theme by default in Android?

Tags: java, android

How to set light theme by default in Android?

I need to know how can I set light theme by default even if the user
enable dark theme in his smart phone with Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by just copying light theme Properties into Night theme file.

**Go to res>values>themes.**

In themes folder, you will see two files `themes.xml` and `themes.xml(night)`.

**Step 1:**

- Copy All `themes.xml` colors and paste them into `themes.xml(night)`.

**Step 2:**

- Replace the Base application theme in both files.

> **Replace this**
>
> `<style name="<app name here>" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`
>
> **to this**
>
> `<style name="Theme.CurrentLocation" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">`